# web page is not shown on blazor application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blazor

I created the sample Blazor application in Visual Studio 2019.

I ran the application and it worked well.

I changed index.razor page as follows:

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you? yes" />
```

I run the application again, but this time a new web browser (chrome) started and stuck in loading page. Nothing shows on the screen.

I opened a chrome window and copy and paste the address from now showing chrome window to new chrome window and it is working properly.

I opened a new tab in the chrome that opened and not showing anything and got the same result.

What the page is not shown on the chrome window that opened by VS?

How can I fix it?

## Edit 1

On the browser that VS opened when I started to debug the application, I can see:
[image]

and if I open a chrome browser and then type the address, I am getting this:

[image]

I checked and the address on both browsers is the same.

The debug log on VS doesn't show any error:

```
Verbose logs are written to:
C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-chrome-debug.txt
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\MyData\TestCode\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1\Server\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\BlazorApp1.Server.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Runtime.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Collections.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\netstandard.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.ComponentModel.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.IO.FileSystem.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Linq.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Threading.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Memory.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Private.Uri.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Xml.XDocument.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Private.Xml.Linq.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Private.Xml.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Threading.Thread.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Threading.Timer.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Text.Json.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Buffers.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Net.Primitives.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.ObjectModel.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Security.Claims.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\MyData\TestCode\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1\Server\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\BlazorApp1.Server.Views.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Linq.Expressions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.JSInterop.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Console.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Collections.Specialized.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\MyData\TestCode\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1\Server\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Security.Principal.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'D:\MyData\TestCode\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1\Server\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\BlazorApp1.Shared.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Metadata.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\System.IO.Pipelines.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. 
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Development
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root path: D:\MyData\TestCode\BlazorApp1\BlazorApp1\Server
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.8\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Net.WebSockets.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.8\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'. 
The thread 0x5d2c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x62f8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1e40 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

## Edit 2

When I press f12, it shows the page correctly and everything is working properly:

[image]

Why do I need to press f12 to show the page during debugging?

## Edit 3

I fund that if I change any part of the application and then try to debug it, it would not show till I press f12. But if press f12 and doesn't change the code or any part of the application, it doesn't need f12 and it works properly on the second run of the application.

## Edit 4

Script debugging is already disabled.
[image]

## Edit 5

I enabled and then disabled script debugging and now when I am trying to run the application, I am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Your message ("Welcome to your new app.") is not in an html tag.

Comment: @gunr2171 I did not change that part. What should I do to fix it? Does not it generate an error on web page or during compile time?

Comment: "Nothing shows" is not helpful as a problem statement. Are there any browser console errors? Does your html get rendered when you view in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Try pressing f12 in the browser while its stuck like that.

Comment: @gunr2171 Please see Edit 1 and Edit 2 which I add more information.

Comment: @BrianParker Why does it work when I press f12? See my Edit 2.

Comment: It is trying to attach to the browser for debugging.'

Comment: @BrianParker Oh ok, So why it can not attach to the browser?

Comment: Try disabling VS Browser Debugging. Click the drop down next to the run button > Script Debugging > Disable. When you open the Dev Tools (F12), whatever was registered as the external debugger (VS) for the browser is kicked out, which might explain why the app suddenly works.

Comment: @gunr2171 Please see Edit 4, The scrip debussing is already disabled.

Comment: I found @gunr2171 advice worked but I had to "toggle" the setting. I guess that cleared it.

Comment: @BrianParker I toggled the Script Debugging and now I am getting this error. Please see Edit 5.

Comment: You have tried restarting VS?

Comment: @BrianParker Yes, but no success! I found this and since my VS was originally installed some months ago, I am now trying to uninstall and reinstalling the latest version to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I uninstall and reinstall my VS to the latest version 16.7.5 but the problem still exists.